# Difference in mvn:idea & mvn::idea

Tags: maven

Simple question, what is difference in following commands or are they same?

Command 1 with single colon

```
mvn:idea
```

Command 2 with 2 colons

```
mvn::idea
```

Comment: Where and when are these commands used?

Comment: I know mvn:idea is a maven plugin to create idea project but I never know double colon idea. Not sure whether it is a valid command at all.

Comment: the idea maven plugin is long deprecated.

Comment: both commands work fine with maven 3